# Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both - Qt

Tags: bash, terminal

Just to precise I'm a total beginner in this. I check on the internet and it seems that nothing match to this problem.

My goal is to run this github which is a facial recognition program: https://github.com/anisayari/easy_facial_recognition

So here is the error:

```
Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both 
/Users/pierre/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtCore (0x1086267f0) 
and /Users/pierre/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib (0x122fc0a80). 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

From what I understand, I just have to indicate which one to use but I don't find anything about how to do it. Also, It seems to be a recurrent error on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this error on my Mac too.  Apparently opencv's GUI tools were conflicting with the PYQT libraries that were also installed on my system in my anaconda/lib/ folder.  So to give opencv just one set of GUI tools and since I wasn't sure what else was using PYQT in my lib, I chose to use the non-GUI version of opencv, aka opencv-python-headless.  I previously had opencv-python-headless installed on my system, and maybe the two packages can't co-exist in the new version of OpenCV or with Catalina.

I removed opencv-python

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

uninstalled and reinstalled the headless version (which has no GUI tools)

```
pip uninstall opencv-python-headless
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

I don't know if it was necessary to remove then reinstall the existing headless package, but that's what I did.  I wasn't sure that opencv-headless would find the PYQT in my lib but it didn't have any problems.